# What is the relation between move semantics and deep/shallow copy?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, shallow-copy

We can implement our own copy constructor if we don't want a shallow copy. So copy constructurs and copy assignment operators are used to implement deep copy.

What sort of relation/interaction do move constructors and assignment operators have with the concepts of deep and shallow copy?

Am I right in saying that move-constructors are used when we *don't* want a deep copy, but rather a shallow copy (and subsequently transfering ownership)?

Comment: Move constructor/assignment operator is used when we do not want a copy (neither shallow nor deep), but we want to move (transfer) contents from one object to another, leaving the moved-from object without its original contents. Move constructors do not perform shallow copy in general.

Comment: `Move constructor` isn't called `Move and copy constructor` for a reason.. It simply moves an object owner .

Comment: You could think of it as a *destructive shallow copy*, where the source is left in an *empty* state

Answer (score 1):

Move construction/assignment is not a logical copy at all. They're transferring ownership; typically, they're implemented similarly to a shallow copy (thus the performance boost), but since the original object is usually emptied in the process, it's not really a copy at all.